# Regex: Trying to match filenames with 6 digit integers

Tags: regex

I am attempting to use the `find` command with a regex to match filenames which contain a 6 digit integer.

This is the command I am running:

```
EVENT_GENERATOR="Se82.2nubb"
find ./ -type f -regex "^./flmyptd2root-$EVENT_GENERATOR-[0-9]{6}.root$"
```

And here are the filenames I expect to match:

```
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000005.root                                                                                             
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000001.root
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000004.root
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000000.root
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000003.root
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-100000.root
./flmyptd2root-Se82.2nubb-000002.root
```

It works if I do this instead:

```
find ./ -type f -regex "^./flmyptd2root-$EVENT_GENERATOR-[0-9]*.root$"
```

But I don't know why that works when the first expression does not. (`*` repeats the match `[0-9]` an arbitrary number of times I believe, so I guess this selects out all possible integers?)

How can I get my expression to select only 6 digit integers?

Comment: Because  the range quantifier should be escaped in POSIX BRE.

Comment: *"... so I guess this selects out all possible integers?"*: including no digit at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use this find command:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended  -type f -regex "^\./flmyptd2root-$EVENT_GENERATOR-[0-9]{6}\.root$"
```

`find` uses BRE by default where `{` and `}` are taken literally, use `-regextype posix-extended` as suggested above to correctly interpret range quantifier `{...}`.

Comment: What is BRE? What is the difference between the different regex types?

Comment: [Check this document for difference between POSIX BRE and POSIX extended](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

Comment: Please be specific on what part you didn't understand. That document states the reason of this problem: `The BRE a{1,2} matches a{1,2} literally, while a\{1,2\} matches a or aa.`

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the difference regex standards. For example, I have discovered that if I force the type to be pozix-awk, then the `{6}` syntax works. If I don't force the type however I do not know how to make the expansion (regex) work.

Comment: Without using a -regextype` range quantifier `{...}` doesn't work on mmany Unix flavors.